# How to fix 'constant x oveflows byte' error in go?

Tags: go, constants, slice

Hello I am trying to make a byte slice with constants but I get the `constant x overflows byte` error.
Here are my constants:

```
const(
     Starttrame1 = 0x10A
     Starttrame2 = 0x10B
     Starttrame3 = 0X10C
     Starttrame4 = 0X10D
     Starttrame5 = 0X10E
     Starttrame6 = 0x10F
)
```

and here is how I declare my slice:

```
var startValues = [6]byte{Starttrame1,Starttrame2,Startrame3,Starttrame4,Starttrame5,Starttrame6}
```

Everytime I build I get the `constant 266 overflows byte`. How should I declare my constants in order to fix this?

Comment: A byte is at most two digits in hex; the maximum byte value is `0xFF` (in any language - this is not Go-specific). If your values are greater than `0xFF` (which all of your values are), you will either have to use smaller values, or use a type bigger than `byte`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Go, `byte` is an alias for `uint8`, which is the set of all unsigned 8-bit integers (`0..255`, both inclusive), see [Spec: Numeric types](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Numeric_types). Which means a value of `0x10A = 266` cannot be stored in a value of type `byte`.

If you need to store those constants, use a different type, e.g. `uint16`:

```
const (
    Starttrame1 = 0x10A
    Starttrame2 = 0x10B
    Starttrame3 = 0X10C
    Starttrame4 = 0X10D
    Starttrame5 = 0X10E
    Starttrame6 = 0x10F
)

var data = [...]uint16{
    Starttrame1, Starttrame2, Starttrame3, Starttrame4, Starttrame5, Starttrame6,
}
```

Try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/FCCONve5m8L).